# Let user to post without registration and identify his post

Tags: php, android, registration

I want that **user can post** on my android app (on a discussion) **without registration**. But I also want to make an identification of the post, who posts the post. I thought I will save user's phone's **IMEI** no to identify him. So that I can show his post to him (on my posts section).

Is it safe to use IMEI? Or is there any way to do my work successfully.
I want to add that I will save the post to my web server.

Comment: So you can't use tablets, then? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android you can save data in the "sharedpreferences" and retrieve the saved key later to display posts made by the user. However, if the user clears your application data, the key is lost. 
An other option, you can use Android MySql, save both userId and postId or just postId. When the user launches the app, get posts from your server. 
Hope this help.

Comment: It's a good idea to save a post id. Once I thought so. But as I am using web server, php to save post, the exact post id may may not be got. Or I don't know the way to get the post id.

Comment: Where do you save the posts? if they are in a DB , you can get the users posts. look into android.database.sqlite for Android Applications, you can save the postId on the mobile app and fetch the same postId from your server.

Comment: I will save my posts on MYSQL database on my web server. But when the post will submit, how to get postId?
One way I know, getting the last post id but if two posts submit at a same time, then what will happen I don't know.

Comment: you are right last post id is what you need. each post submission will return the post id entered into the table.

Answer (score -2):

im not that much in android app development, but it is possible to change the IMEI number of android phones easily.

Also, if 2 users want to use the application on the same smartphone, there will be an issue.

if you don't set up registration with at least email, im not sure you can log which user posted what.

Comment: You are right. But my apps is for the students who wanna sit for a particular exam. And may be there will not be too much user. Thanks for ur advice.

Comment: so why don't you just use the student's logins ?
I presume in your school, there is an identication name for each students right ?

Comment: also, you could check this post, that should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: It's not for school. And I am trying to find a way without registration.